# How deploy upgradeable contract using metamask on browser

Tags: next.js, metamask, hardhat

pages/deploy.js

```
import { ethers, upgrade } from "hardhat";
import { useState } from "react";
import BOX from "../artifacts/contracts/Box.sol/Box.json";

function Box() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    const [contract, setContract] = useState("");
    const deployBox = async () => {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const Box = await ethers.getContractFactory(BOX.abi, BOX.bytecode, signer);
        console.log("Deploying Box...");
        const box = await upgrades.deployProxy(Box, [42], { initializer: "store" });
        console.log("Box deployed to:", box.address);
        setContract(box.address);
    };
    const getBox = async () => {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const Box = new ethers.Contract(contract, BOX.abi, signer);
        const value = await Box.retrieve();
        setValue(value.toString());
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={deployBox}>Deploy Box</button>
            <button onClick={getBox}>Get Value</button>
            <p>{value}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Box;
```

I'm experiencing issues running the code provided in a browser.

Can Hardhat be used to deploy contracts directly in the browser, or is it primarily designed for command-line interface use?

What are some alternative methods for deploying upgradeable contracts in the browser?

Could you please provide suggestions for such methods?